# How to get the MLE estimate of a factor analysis model?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

Given a factor analysis model  $$ X-\mu = LF + \epsilon$$
Lets denote $cov[\epsilon] = \Psi$ and $cov[X] = \Sigma$. $\Psi$ is assumed to be a diagnal matrix.

The iterative MLE estimate exploits the fact that:
$$\hat{\Psi}^{0.5}*S_n*\hat{\Psi}^{0.5}$$ has eigenvector $\hat{\Psi}^{0.5}\hat{L}$ and eigenvalue $1 + \hat\delta_i$.

Using this result, we can start from an initial estimate of $\Psi$ and then iteratively solve for L. Using the formula $\hat{L} = \hat{\Psi}^{0.5}\hat{E}(\hat\Lambda - I)^{0.5}$ where $\hat E$ is the matrix of eigenvectors and $\hat\Lambda$ is a diagnal matrix of eigenvalues.

The problem I have with this approach is what is there to ganrantee that the matrix $\hat\Lambda - I$ has positive diaganl entries? If not, taking a square root will not make sense.